# Remote tunnel setup stuck on github signin

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, remote-access, vscode-remote, tunneling

I would like to preface that I am new to stack overflow as a whole and I hope this is the proper way to ask questions here, if not please let me know how I can improve.
Before I get to the main problem I should address my end goal as I am not exactly sure if the way I am attempting to achieve this goal is the correct method. What I want is to be able to use my desktop PC, which is on a different network to which I do not have permissions to setup port-forwarding on (On a college campus' network), from my chromebook. For a while I have been using chrome remote desktop but this is starting to get really frustraiting as the 0.5-1 second delay is impeading my efficiency greatly over long sessions. When I saw that you could remote tunnel to a PC I thought this would be perfect for this. I also saw the Remote - SSH capability but I could not use this as I could not port-forward on the campus wifi. If my approach to this dilema is not the best then please inform me of a better alternative and ignore the question stated below.

The issue I am having is that I setup a remote tunnel on my PC at my dorm.
[Host PC tunnel setup confirmed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXzJM.png)
Then when using my chromebook I have VSCode installed on the Linux Ubuntu VM and when I attempt to use the remote tunnel through VSCode on my chromebook I get perpetually stuck at this stage:
[VSCode on Chromebook signin stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ss59S.png)
If any additional info is needed please let me know and I will do my best to provide it.

I have been searching for an answer to this issue for nearly 6 hours over 2 days now but unfortunately I have yet to find anyone with this same issue.

Below is all of the corresponding output logs when encountering this issue, these were pulled from the output terminal on my Chromebook.

Github - Authentication:

```
2023-03-09 14:52:25.239 [info] Reading sessions from keychain...
2023-03-09 14:52:25.239 [info] Getting sessions for read:org,user:email...
2023-03-09 14:52:25.239 [info] Got 0 sessions for read:org,user:email...
2023-03-09 14:52:25.239 [info] Getting sessions for all scopes...
2023-03-09 14:52:25.239 [info] Got 0 sessions for ...
2023-03-09 14:52:27.997 [info] Logging in for the following scopes: read:org user:email
2023-03-09 14:52:28.004 [info] Trying without local server... (read:org user:email)
2023-03-09 14:54:46.504 [error] User Cancelled
2023-03-09 14:54:47.387 [info] Trying with local server... (read:org user:email)
2023-03-09 14:54:59.109 [error] User Cancelled
2023-03-09 14:55:00.509 [error] Error: Cancelled
    at r (/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/github-authentication/dist/extension.js:2:1012216)
    at async t.GitHubServer.login (/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/github-authentication/dist/extension.js:2:1012839)
    at async t.GitHubAuthenticationProvider.createSession (/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/github-authentication/dist/extension.js:2:1009192)
2023-03-09 14:55:00.683 [info] Getting sessions for read:org,user:email...
2023-03-09 14:55:00.683 [info] Got 0 sessions for read:org,user:email...
2023-03-09 14:55:00.820 [info] Getting sessions for user:email...
2023-03-09 14:55:00.820 [info] Got 0 sessions for user:email...
2023-03-09 14:55:01.153 [info] Getting sessions for all scopes...
2023-03-09 14:55:01.153 [info] Got 0 sessions for ...
```

Microsoft - Authentication:

```
2023-03-09 14:55:01.139 [info] Reading sessions from secret storage...
2023-03-09 14:55:01.139 [info] Got 0 stored sessions
2023-03-09 14:55:01.139 [info] Getting sessions for the following scopes: email offline_access openid profile
2023-03-09 14:55:01.139 [info] Got 0 sessions for scopes: email offline_access openid profile
```

Remote - Tunnels (Host PC name is "PigRig"):

```
2023-03-09 14:52:25.194 [info] Resolving tunnel+PigRig...
```

Extension Host:

```
2023-03-09 14:52:25.092 [info] Extension host with pid 8923 started
2023-03-09 14:52:25.103 [info] [resolveAuthority(tunnel,1)][0ms] activating resolver...
2023-03-09 14:52:25.133 [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension ms-vscode.remote-server, startup: false, activationEvent: 'onResolveRemoteAuthority:tunnel'
2023-03-09 14:52:25.175 [info] [resolveAuthority(tunnel,1)][72ms] setting tunnel factory...
2023-03-09 14:52:25.175 [info] [resolveAuthority(tunnel,1)][72ms] invoking resolve()...
2023-03-09 14:52:25.204 [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.github-authentication, startup: false, activationEvent: 'onAuthenticationRequest:github'
2023-03-09 14:52:26.177 [info] [resolveAuthority(tunnel,1)][1073ms] waiting...
2023-03-09 14:52:27.177 [info] [resolveAuthority(tunnel,1)][2074ms] waiting...

...

2023-03-09 14:54:59.294 [info] [resolveAuthority(tunnel,1)][154191ms] waiting...
2023-03-09 14:55:00.296 [info] [resolveAuthority(tunnel,1)][155193ms] waiting...
2023-03-09 14:55:00.517 [error] [resolveAuthority(tunnel,1)][155414ms] returned an error {"name":"Error","message":"Cancelled"}
2023-03-09 14:55:00.623 [info] Eager extensions activated
2023-03-09 14:55:00.770 [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers, startup: false, activationEvent: 'onStartupFinished'
2023-03-09 14:55:00.805 [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl, startup: false, activationEvent: 'onStartupFinished'
2023-03-09 14:55:01.007 [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.microsoft-authentication, startup: false, activationEvent: 'onAuthenticationRequest:microsoft'
```

Things that I have already tried:

- I tried Remote - SSH but this did not work as I cannot setup a port-forward on the campus' network.
- I have tried re-installing VSCode on both computers.
- I have tried the web browser version which will not let me open any folders but i can see all of my directories, when opening a folder it either asks me to select a folder again or reloads the page and fails to load the folder, again prompting me to select a folder. The browser version is not desireable to me as I would prefer to have it just in the app on my vhromebook and not in a tab.
- I have tried removing and re-doing the tunnel on the host PC, this also did not work and changed nothing.